# Can I insert typed in values as well as selected data into a temporary table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, temp-tables

I want to create a temporary table that gives me a file spec. The table will be two columns; one with the column name (a value that is not in my db), the other is the values permitted in that column (in many cases these are values from the db). Is this possible? I've tried the below, which doesn't work, but might help to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO #fileSpec (columnName,[value])

('myValue',table1.fieldName)
FROM dbo.table1
WHERE fieldDescription = 'criteria'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO #fileSpec (columnName,[value])
    SELECT 'myValue', table1.fieldName
    FROM dbo.table1
    WHERE fieldDescription = 'criteria';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
insert into (columnName, value) (select 'myValue', able1.fieldName from dbo.table1
WHERE fieldDescription = 'criteria');
```